# What does caffe do with the mean-binary file ?

Tags: caffe

In the caffe-input layer one can define a mean image that holds mean values of all the images used. From the image net example: "The model requires us to subtract the image mean from each image, so we have to compute the mean".

My question is: What is the implementation of this subtraction? Is it simply :

```
used_image = original_image - mean_image
```

or

```
used_image = mean_image - original_iamge
```

or

```
used_image = |original_image - mean_image|^2
```

if it is one of the first two, then how are negative pixels handeld ? Since the pictures are usually stored in uint8 it would mean that it simply starts from the beginning. e.g

> 200 - 255 = 56

Why I need to know this? I made tests and I know that the second example or the third example would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first one, a trivial normalization step.  Using the second instead wouldn't really matter: the weights would invert.

There are no "negative pixels", per se: this is simply integer input to the matrix operations.  *You* are welcome to interpret this as a visual alteration of some sort, but the arithmetic doesn't care.

Comment: Thank you, I was digging through the source code and just found it (line 115 in data_transformer.cpp) .

Comment: Good sleuthing -- now you have the knowledge first-hand, along with other learning picked up along the way.

Comment: I just had a discussion about this: Since this is done in the input layer it might be , that this code takes already part on the GPU where it is all converted to float, so that would mean that a dark pixel becomes a negative number

Comment: No problem.  It's merely the result of a linear transformation function from the original pixel value.  The pixel is not negative, per se: the brightness in merely below the mean.  The arithmetic will work with this as easily as all positive values.